# PHPUnit Error: Call to undefined method Controller::request()

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

On running this test, I get **Error: Call to undefined method OrderControllerTest::request()**

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
class OrderControllerTest extends TestCase
{

  public function testupload() {
    $a='foo';
    $output = $this->request('POST',['Order', 'upload',$a] );
  }
}
```

PHPUNIT Version: 7.2.4. Appreciate any help

Comment: Did you define `request` method? As `TestCase` does not have it.

Comment: u_mulder No, I was expecting `request` to be a built in class in like the example in https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test . How can I invoke a controller action passing its arguments?

Comment: In Symfony it is `WebTestCase`. Google something similar for Codeigniter.

Comment: Package you provided extends phpunit functionality. Install this package and use it.

Comment: u_mulder which package ? BTW I'm new to PHP :S . Also my model tests pass with `TestCase`

Comment: This https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test

Comment: I already installed it but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Maybe you extend incorrect class.

Comment: which class should I be extending then ?

Comment: $this->request going to find method of current class so there is no request method in your class. to execute it make method with name request and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For the [kenjis/ci-phpunit-test](https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test) package if you run phpunit from the application/tests folder so it picks up on the included phpunit.xml and included TestCase Class then they should run.

`cd application/tests`

then, if you are using the composer installed version of phpunit in your project:

`../../vendor/bin/phpunit`

or if you're using the globally (apt etc.) installed version simply:

`phpunit`

see http://blog.a-way-out.net/blog/2015/06/12/codeigniter3-phpunit/#how-to-run-tests

Answer (score 0):

The package [kenjis/ci-phpunit-test](https://github.com/kenjis/ci-phpunit-test) extends the standard PHPUnit package so what you need to do is to extend the `CIPHPUnitTestCase` instead like in example below.

```
<?php

class OrderControllerTest extends CIPHPUnitTestCase
{

  public function testupload() {
    $a='foo';
    $output = $this->request('POST',['Order', 'upload',$a] );
  }
}
```

You may need to configure your IDE so that it can find `CIPHPUnitTestCase` class.